# What differences could be affecting a SOLR indexing when using Docker in EC2 rather than Docker-compose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solr, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a docker container with Solr in **Amazon EC2** using Amazon ECS [(dockerfile)](https://github.com/datacite/search/blob/labs/Dockerfile). Takes a Database and save the index in an **EFS volumen**. As in my drawing.

[image: my setup]

However, the indexing is never complete and errors are never thrown out in the logs.

I have a similar setup on my local machine (without the EFS volume) but using `docker-compose` [(.yml file)](https://github.com/datacite/search/blob/labs/docker-compose.yml) and the indexing works pretty well.

*I made an experiment*, I installed `docker-compose` in **EC2** and ran the same container. The results? The indexing works fine. It indexes the whole database.

I have found NO difference in:

- Env variables.
- ran `Docker inspect` on either of the containers [both files](https://gist.github.com/kjgarza/8d8a80bab10e2c1c2e07f7e49deb6c16)

What could be causing the I have different results indexing the database when using `docker-compose` as oppose to using `ECS`??